# UK visa Evidence of permission to be in country

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

Applying UK tourist visa- Need help for "Evidence of Permission to be in the country".I am on H1b visa which is valid for next one year. First two page of petition (I797) and recent I94 should be good ? Do I need to send anything of my home country?

Comment: Where are you now? USA?

Comment: Your passport is the only evidence of your  home country you will need, and naturally you will be sending it along.

Comment: @user56513 if that is an answer, please submit it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your passport is the only evidence of your home country you will need, and naturally you will be sending it along.

I assume in addition to your approved petition, you have a valid H-1B **visa**. That will be needed particularly if your travel itinerary calls for returning to the USA directly. The UK will like that to know you have right of entry to where your outbound flight takes you as you depart the UK.

### Reference

Former H-1B myself.